# jqgrid expand after hiddengrid:true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Creating JQGRID object i put hiddengrid:true.
Now, to expand grid i need to press special button on the right
I want it to expand automatically during update

something like this:

```
function updateTable(value,date_in,date_out) {
  $('#le_table1').jqGrid('setGridParam', {gridstate: "visible"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
};
```

but is not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close",$('#le_table1')[0].grid.cDiv).click();
```

to simulate the click on the small button from the right side of the grid title which expand/collapse the grid (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344038/jquery-jqgrid-expand-collapse-grid-on-caption-layer-click/4344176#4344176) for details and some demo examples).

Answer (score 8):

you can use method **setGridState**:

- $("#grid_id").jqGrid('setGridState', 'visible');
- $("#grid_id").jqGrid('setGridState', 'hidden');

Comment: thank you buddy. grid.cDiv).click(); was very buggy... I did not find this way setting gridstate any where. thank you verymuch.

Comment: This answer reverses the effect of setting 'hiddengrid: true' in your grid declaration. Just what I was looking for.